# Using a "const" before multiple commas and objects

Tags: c++, constants

So the question is this:

```
const int ci = 0, &cj = ci;
```

so does the `const` entitle every object after its created? does this read "ci is a const int" and "cj is a reference to a const int" as well? or is &cj not a const and just means "a reference to ci"?

if the const DOES encompass the entire line, what about this...

```
int j = i;
const int &k = i; 
int *p = &i;
```

now that the const is in the middle, does it ignore the first object and create a const for everything in front of it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: There are too many questions in here (I count 4). Please narrow it.  Refer to [ask].

Comment: This seems pretty easy to test for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In variable declarations, the type name and qualifiers apply to all the variables being declared in that statement. So in your first example, both `ci` and `&cj` are declared as `const int`.

In your second example, each declaration is a separate statement. The type names and qualifiers don't have any effect on different statements.